# Retrieve matching element from string

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Using bash I have a string that holds my deployed applications:

```
APPS="myapp-a-1.0.war myapp-b-1.1.war myapp-c-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war"
```

I can determine whether a specific app is deployed:

```
if [[ "$APPS" == *myapp-a* ]]
then
    echo "myapp-a is deployed, but we don't know the version."
fi
```

How can I retrieve the complete matching word (application with version) given that I only have the  words prefix (application name, e.g. 'myapp-a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your variable (provided you don't quote it):

```
for app in ${APPS}; do
  if [[ "${app}" == myapp-a* ]]; then
    echo ${app}
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

as simple as:

```
if [[ "$APPS" =~ myapp\-a([^war]*)war ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} deployed"
fi
```

result in:

```
myapp-a-1.0.war deployed
```

if you need only version:

```
if [[ "$APPS" =~ myapp\-a([^war]*)war ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} deployed"
fi
```

result in:

```
-1.0. deployed
```

if you need version without artefacts like dashes, dots:

```
if [[ "$APPS" =~ myapp\-a\-([^war]*)\.war ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} deployed"
fi
```

result in:

```
1.0 deployed
```

Comment: Thanks. These are great examples provided.